Primary DisplayPort Monitor connection not recognized by GUI. Works in GRUB
Kubuntu displayport Dell Optiplex 9010 Dell Monitor, Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000 monitor displays GRUB after selecting Kubuntu display goes black
My ancient Dell 9010 Optiplex runs Windows 10 adequately, but given that end of life is coming up for 10,  I thought I'd migrate to Linux.
Problem:  The Dell Monitor displays Grub content fine on boot up, but once Kubuntu is selected the monitor ceases to display content, when connected via Displayport.
IF I plug the monitor in the VGA port of the computer and monitor THEN it does work.   I'd prefer to run it with the display port cable.
Tips and suggestions appreciated!
About this system: Running: Kubuntu 24.04  Plasma Ver: 5.27.11 KDE Frameworks: 5.115.0 Qt Ver: 5.15.13
Kernal Ver: 6.8.0-35-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
i7-3770 Intel CPU 3.40Ghz
11.6 GiB of FrameworksGraphics Processor: Mesa Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000
Dell Optiplex 9010
Sys Ver: 01
